# executable ruby1.8 missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, redmine

So I was trying to install redmine on an apache2 server on Ubuntu.
Between multiple atemps to install a plugin, I "accidentaly" deleted /usr/bin/ruby1.8.

Now I get this error when I try to launch redmine with ruby2.0 (even after a rvm install 1.8) : 
`*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/bin/ruby1.8: No such file or directory (2)`

What should I do to have this executable back ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Probably just need to relink. Do `whereis ruby`, find the version 1.8 that rvm installed, then create a symlink using `ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.8 path/to/newly/installed/ruby1.8`. That should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect ruby1.8 was the already installed system ruby; can check with `dpkg --get-selections | grep ruby` .  If this is the case, I would uninstall ruby 1.8 from rvm and then reinstall the system ruby through apt.
Once that's been cleared up, and you have a /usr/bin/ruby1.8 again, check/manage your available rubies through rvm:

- `rvm list`
- `rvm use <ruby version>`

etc.

Comment: It seems like, with dpkg I got :
`libruby1.8                                      install
libruby1.9.1                                    install
libruby1.9.1-dbg                                install
libtcltk-ruby1.9.1                              install
ruby                                            install
ruby-dev                                        install
ruby1.8                                         install
ruby1.8-dev                                     install
ruby1.9.1                                       install
rubygems                                        install`

Comment: Thanks for you help.
All I had to do is to remove ruby from rvm, then `apt-get remove ruby1.8
apt-get install ruby1.8-full
apt-get install rubygems`

ruby1.8 binary reapeared in /usr/bin and I can now use ruby2.0 from rvm